# How do you make a custom popup in tkinter using two seperate classes and inheritance?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to look for an answer to this question for the last hour and I have not found anything.  (I feel like this should be on the internet).

I am trying to make a custom popup when you click a button on the parent GUI frame.  I then want the user to input variables, and then have those variables be returned to the original class.  I am essentially making a popup to enter options.  However, I should note that not all of the options have to be entered, it just depends on the user's situation.  The user can click the "options" button at any time as well, so when the popup is quit, I would like it to return to the parent GUI at the time the options button was originally hit.  What I was doing is the following:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Home(Frame):  #This class defines the main(master) GUI

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

    #Other methods in class "Home" that get, variables, etc.

    def call_popup(self):
        options_popup = Options(self)

        #wait_window does not work here
        self.master.wait_window(options_popup)

class Options(Toplevel):    #This class defines the popup GUI

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.popup = self

    #Other methods in class "Options"

    def get_variable(self): #Just an example methods in class "Options"
        #Simplified code but lets say I now have the variable foo in self.foo, unique to class "Options"
    #I want to pass this variable back to class "Home"

    def exit_popup(self):
        self.popup.destroy()

        #I want it to return to the spot that the user was originally at
        #when they hit the "options button" in the home GUI.  I also want all
        #values inputted in the "options" popup to return to the class "Home"

root = Tk()
Home(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I believe a (big) part of the problem is that I am pretty new with classes (as well as Tkinter).

I have looked at a lot of questions about tkinter, popups, inheritance with classes and wait_window and I unfortunately still can't figure it out.

I have also tried passing the class "Options" like this: `def __init__(self, master, options):` (line 3), yet that exceeded the number of arguments.

So, main questions:
-How do I pass variables from popup/class "Options" to class "Home"?
-How do you have the popup/class "Options" window wait until closed to resume back to the class "Home"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I believe that I've implemented the stuff you are having problems with in your code, see below for further explanations:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Home(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entryvalue = None  # this will store the popop entry value
        self.call_popup(self)
        print("Popup closed!")
        print("Entry value:" + self.entryvalue)

    def call_popup(self, master):
        options_popup = Options(master)
        options_popup.wait_window()



class Options(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        # add an entry widget
        self.e1 = Entry(self)
        self.e1.pack()

        # add a button
        b1 = Button(self, text="Popup button", command=self.buttonpressed)
        b1.pack()

    def buttonpressed(self):
        self.master.entryvalue = self.e1.get()
        self.exit_popup()

    def exit_popup(self):
        self.destroy()


root = Tk()
Home(root)
root.mainloop()
```

For your first question. You need to provide the popup/options object with a reference to the object where you want your data to end up, in this case in the home object. As you can see I'm passing this as a new argument to the **init** method of the popup. I've then added a command to the button which will then set the entryvalue variable in the home object. This could also have been a function call or similiar.

For having the code wait for the window to finish, you should call the wait_window() method on the options_popup object, as this is the one you are waiting for. You could also move it to the **init** method of the popup window and invoke it on self instead.

For more information regarding dialog windows, you should look at this [article](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm). This dialog support class example is pretty good I think.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I wasn't able to work on this right away but when I did, it worked perfectly.  I did have to change a few things because I forgot to mention that the popup only shows up when the user presses a button in the home object, not automatically as it does in this case when you run the GUI.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped!