# How open a main Windows with menubar and click in the menu for open another window and returning value to mainWindow

Tags: python, class, tkinter, return, menubar

Used the code the answer from [anderswb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158292/how-do-you-make-a-custom-popup-in-tkinter-using-two-seperate-classes-and-inherit)

I need to open de MainWindow, select “New place” from the menubar, open the SubWindow from child.py, select a value from the combo and return that value concatenate with a text to the main window.

The code opens the two windows at the same time.

I want to know what is wrong with this code.

This is my code:

`parent.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from child import *

class MainWindow(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entryvalue = None  # this will store the popop entry value

        menudemagare =Menu(master)
        master.config(menu=menudemagare)

        #creation du menu fichier
        menu_fichier = Menu(menudemagare)
        menudemagare.add_cascade(label="Fichier",menu=menu_fichier)
        menu_fichier.add_command(label="NeW place",command=self.geValueSubWindow(self))

    
    def geValueSubWindow(self, master):
        optionWindow = SubWindow(master)
        optionWindow.wait_window()
        print("Entry value:" + self.entryvalue)


root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

`child.py`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class SubWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.varValue = ""

        self.arrondissement_combo = ttk.Combobox(self,value=[45, 46],width=45)
        self.arrondissement_combo.current(0)
        self.arrondissement_combo.pack(pady=12)
        self.arrondissement_combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.secteur_select)

    def secteur_select(self,event):
        self.varValue = self.arrondissement_combo.get()
        self.master.entryvalue = self.varValue + " units"
        self.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SubWindow()
```

Comment: Hi TheLizzard. thanks for the anwer Hi TheLizzard. Thanks for the answer, the first solution works well but I want to try the second one, but it gives me the error: parent.py", line 26, in <module>
    MainWindow(root)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The parent code is:
Parent.py

Comment: class MainWindow(Frame):
        def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.entryvalue = None 
        menudemagare =Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menudemagare)
        menu_fichier = Menu(menudemagare)
        menudemagare.add_cascade(label="Fichier",menu=menu_fichier)
        menu_fichier.add_command(label="NeW place",command=lambda: self.geValueSubWindow(self))
    def geValueSubWindow(self):
        optionWindow = SubWindow(self)
        optionWindow.wait_window()

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()

Comment: I am not sure if you were addressing me(@Art) as TheLizzard. For the second solution you need to change `command=lambda: self.geValueSubWindow(self))` to `command=self.geValueSubWindow`